# Where to mention schema while connecting to postgres using sqlalchemy in python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Using below code to connect to postgres connects me to the default public schema. Where can i mention
the schema name in the connection string? I am trying to insert the data. So when I use `dataframe.to_sql('myschema.mytable', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)`

It creates a table name with myschema.mytable in public schema instead of inserting the data into mytable which already exist under myschema.

I am using sqlalchemy library in python. Below is my connection string.

```
engine = create_engine('postgres://user:password@host:5432/dbname')
```

I tried the jdbc way by appending ?currentSchema=schemaname and ?schema=schemaname but both does not work.

Comment: In Postgres you connect to a database, you do not connect to a schema. It seems you have connected to public as that is the only schema in your [search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-set.html). You can use either standard dot notation (schema_name.object_name) of set the appropriate path as "set search_path to my_schema, public";

Answer (score 0):

@Belayer, thanks for the response. After some more research, it seems you can mention the schema name while loading the data to database.

```
dataframe.to_sql('mytable', con=connection, schema='myschema',if_exists='append', index=False)
```